# Angular / JS Upload image to AWS pre Signed URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services

Every time I try and upload an image to a pre signed url. I receive the preflight warning and the upload fails.

What do i need to do?

[image]

as far as Im aware I should be uploading to the url that can be seen in url attribute in the image.

I have tried all sorts of variations to this but this is my current upload code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: pData.url,
      // Content type must much with the parameter you signed your URL with
      contentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
      // this flag is important, if not set, it will try to send data as a form
      processData: false,
      // the actual file is sent raw
      data: $scope.file
    })
    .success(function() {
      alert('File uploaded');
    })
    .error(function() {
      alert('File NOT uploaded');
      console.log( arguments);
    });
```

How do i trouble shoot this, I have no access to the backend that gives me the signed url, Is it likely that the person in charge or amazon has the CORS wrong and how can i check this?

thanks for any advise.

Comment: Did you get a response to this? I am facing the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS issue. You need to ask the admin to put this to the CORS configuration of the S3 Bucket.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```